# Shouldn't this question on a current event be closed?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, scope, current-events

A question here raised scepticism about a report from a former (?) journalist of how the US sabotaged the Nordstream pipeline in Europe - [Did the CIA blow up the Nordstream 1 pipeline?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/54372/67479)

This is a question on a *current event* and a *military operation*. None of the countries investigating the blast (and there are many) have so far released any information publicly. All claim to be still investigating the matter. So information on this is really scant to non-existent. The expose by a reputed journalist, based on whistle-blower(s) account, is the only relevant news on this subject and the question is based on that report. Obviously, the journalist cannot reveal the whistle-blower(s) identity, and thus, it is easy to be sceptical about the report.

If, as Skeptics.SE likes to highlight, only questions that can be answered factually should be encouraged here, the question I have pointed to should have been deleted due to the *lack of relevant, factual info* on the subject. (I believe that was the justification too in not allowing questions on Jeffrey Epstein's death?).

And yet, it is allowed, and we have highly upvoted *sub-standard answers* based on so called "open source" intelligence (which is ridiculous when you consider that any public information about military operations are now a days deliberately tainted as part of [information warfare and cyberwarfare](https://www.rand.org/pubs/monograph_reports/MR661.html), and that is more so likely the case with this event too as NATO / EU is on a wartime alert due to the Russian-Ukraine conflict).

As such, shouldn't this question on a *current event* and a *military operation* (or an act of international terrorism) be deleted?

*(Note: My answer to this question was deleted and I have made a [separate meta post](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4945/67479) about it too).*

Comment: If you think the answer's that no-one's really sure yet, then you could probably write it up.  Relevant references might help.

Comment: To note it, unfortunately SE.Skeptics answers don't tend to be too reliably factually accurate.  It's kind of a limitation.

Comment: What was your answer to the question?

Comment: @Nat I did write an answer that was deleted. Please see this meta question which refers to it - https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4945/67479

Answer (score 4):

This is a question about a specific article written by Seymour Hersh in the end, even though the title is more general. But the text of the question is clear that this is about whether the account by Hersh is correct.

A question about who blew up the pipelines directly after it happened might have been closed for the reason you mention. But this is a question about a very specific theory claimed by Hersh, there are many more avenues to evaluate this compared to just "who blew up the pipeline".

Comment: Yeah I think it's causing some confusion that the question title looks so much broader than its actual content, it'd be better if the title was tightened up. In fact... I'll just do that

Answer (score -5):

I tend to think that policy was created more to mitigate controversy by quelling discussion until it is more or less forgotten and the news cycle has moved on, more than it was to protect the veracity of this SE.

I think people can judge for themselves and by the comments whether or not an answer is making a qualifying judgement, and I think it would probably only get deleted if it was feared by the moderation to have serious political ramifications against their favour.

Personally I don't think most questions or any [effort based] answers should ever be deleted, especially on this particular SE, because skepticism requires hearing all ideas, especially heterodox [unpopular] ones.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/145440/discussion-on-answer-by-anon-shouldnt-this-question-on-a-current-event-be-close); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.